# Netbeans installation error, not able to find JDK path automatically

Tags: java, netbeans, installation, netbeans-8

I'm using 64-bit Windows 8.1 and I've installed *java-13* and *jre1.8*.

When I try to install netbeans it is not able to detect JDK automatically and when I try to give JDK path manually it's not able to proceed with the installation because the next button is disabled.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you are giving it the correct path for the JDK installation?  According to the documentation, the default locations appear to be: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0" and "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13".  But you have installed them with different names.  Use a directory browser to find what they are on your system.

Comment: NetBeans 8.0 will not work with any version of Java > 8. If you want to use java > 8 you need to install [Apache NetBeans 11](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html)

Comment: I agree with Stephen. Locate the _JDK for the NetBeans IDE_ directory by clicking its **Browse...** button, and navigate to it. This eliminates the possibility of mistyping the path. For the most recent release of JDK 8 (update 221), the directory you want to select will probably be named **jdk1.8.0_221**, and if you can't find that directory then you should probably [download and install 8u221](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) first.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to install Netbeans 8.0.2 and I already had Java 13 installed but whenever I try to install the Netbeans 8.0.2, it was giving me an error stating 'JDK not found, please install JDK' so I figured out that Netbeans works when you have java 8, so my advice is **first download Java 8 and provide the path of bin in environment variables(on Windows) then install Netbeans.** 
I hope It will work for you.